# BUG con el widget OptionMenu en tkinter: Todos los menus adoptan el mismo valor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy haciendo un programa sencillo de un temporizador usando tkinter para la interfaz de usuario. Lo que pretendo hacer es añadir las horas, minutos y segundos al temporizador haciendo uso del widget OptionMenu. El problema aparece cuando se abre la ventana hija donde se encuentran estos widgets. Como se puede ver en el gif que he proporcionado, si en el menu de horas pongo, por ejemplo, 12, el resto de menus adquieren el mismo valor.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como puedo arreglar eso para que todos los menus adquieran un valor independiente, además también me gustaría saber como puedo leer los datos de esos menus para usarlos en el código. Adjunto el código que se ejecuta cuando se pulsa el boton "Edit" de la ventana padre:

```
 def set_config_window(self):
    config_window = tk.Toplevel()
    config_window.geometry(CONFIG_WINDOW_SIZE)
    config_window.resizable(0,0)
    default_option = tk.StringVar()
    default_option.set("0")
    # Defining Labels
    hour_label = tk.Label(config_window, text="Hours")
    mins_label = tk.Label(config_window,text="Minuts")
    secs_label = tk.Label(config_window,text="Seconds")
    # Placing Labels
    hour_label.place(x=HOURS_LABEL_X, y=HOURS_LABEL_Y)
    mins_label.place(x=MINS_LABEL_X, y=MINS_LABEL_Y)
    secs_label.place(x=SECS_LABEL_X, y=SECS_LABEL_Y)
    # Defining menus BUG
    hours_menu = tk.OptionMenu(config_window, default_option, *HOURS)
    mins_menu = tk.OptionMenu(config_window, default_option, *MINS)
    secs_menu = tk.OptionMenu(config_window, default_option, *SECS)
    # Placing menus
    hours_menu.place(x=HOURS_MENU_X, y=HOURS_MENU_Y)
    mins_menu.place(x=MINS_MENU_X, y=MINS_MENU_Y)
    secs_menu.place(x=SECS_MENU_X, y=SECS_MENU_Y)
```

NOTA: Los nombres que se encuentran en mayúscula son variables que tengo almacenadas en otro script de python y que están importadas como módulo en el script del timer. Adjunto las variables:

```
HOURS = range(0, 100, 1)
MINS = range(0, 60, 1)
SECS = range(0, 60, 1)

#! ABSOLUTE POSITIONS

HOURS_MENU_X = 51
HOURS_MENU_Y = 70
MINS_MENU_X = 215
MINS_MENU_Y = 70
SECS_MENU_X = 387
SECS_MENU_Y = 70
HOURS_LABEL_X = 51
HOURS_LABEL_Y = 50
MINS_LABEL_X = 215
MINS_LABEL_Y = 50
SECS_LABEL_X = 387
SECS_LABEL_Y = 50
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Necesitas un Intvar para cada uno parece que esta usando el mismo para los 3

Comment: No es obligatorio que sean IntVars. Pueden ser StringVars si deseas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explicación

No es un bug, si no una característica. Si tienes varios widgets asociados a una variable de control (en tu caso StringVar) y uno de los widgets cambia el valor del stringvar, entonces todos los widgets mostraran el nuevo valor.

Por ejemplo imagina que tienes tres entrys:

```
sv = StringVar()

Entry(textvariable=sv)
Entry(textvariable=sv)
Entry(textvariable=sv)
```

Si escribes algo en un entry, en los otros dos se va a escribir lo mismo simultáneamente.

En tu código, estás usando la misma variable de control para los tres option menu, lo cual crea el mismo efecto que sucede con los Entrys y por lo tanto causa el "bug".

## Solución

Para solucionar tu problema tienes que tener una variable de control (en tu caso StringVar) por cada option menu que crees.

Aquí te dejo un codigo de ejemplo:

```
# Con el parametro value puedes indicar con que valor inicia el StringVar
default_option1 = tk.StringVar(value="0")
default_option2 = tk.StringVar(value="0")
default_option3 = tk.StringVar(value="0")

hours_menu = tk.OptionMenu(config_window, default_option1, *HOURS)
mins_menu = tk.OptionMenu(config_window, default_option2, *MINS)
secs_menu = tk.OptionMenu(config_window, default_option3, *SECS)
```

## Aclaraciones

Debido al nombre de la variable que elegiste para crear el StringVar (default_option) creo que crees que el proposito del StringVar es dar un valor default al option menu.
Si ese el el caso, te aviso que los StringVars no cumplen este proposito. Su proposito es por ejemplo guardar lo escrito en un entry. O si el checkbutton tiene la tilde o no.

Te recomiendo leer esta pagina para entender mejor como funcionan las variables de control: https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/02/variables-de-control-en-tkinter.html